# how to Communicate with a server and show the details on phone automatically

Tags: android, database, authentication

I want to make an app in which one would input their ID and PASSWORD. This would be parsed to the server and would communicate with the server database such that it would give the details related to that username and password back to the phone and the details would be displayed there

Once logged in the mobile is always connected with the server and updates the details after a specified time interval

How should I proceed in development of this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need is developing Web Service that will commuincate with your remote database and has all the function that you need like for example authenticating the user, get his/her profile and so on, this has nothing to do with android development, and once you done with that  use Ksoap2 library to help your app commuincate with the Web Service developed up and here is a link can help you to do so 
[Click here](http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/15/introduction-to-working-with-ksoap2-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You should start with reading the following tutorial on android & network connection:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: and when you're done reading that, read up on Android Services - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html